# How can I tell if I have interior or exterior drain tile?

Tags: plumbing, water, basement, waterproofing

Is it possible to tell which one you have? Here is a picture of my sump pit, the pipe is facing in towards the inside of the house:

[image: sump pit]

Here is a picture of my foundation blueprints:

[image: blueprints]

It appears the drain tile is on the inside next to the foundation wall footing. But I can't be sure because the blueprints also say it's a concrete block wall and it's actually poured. So I'm not sure how to tell. Is it possible to know?

Comment: That's a boilerplate diagram. It may not relate to the specifications for your home.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can look for yourself!  Trim back the corrugated tubing a bit, then run a usb borescope camera down it.
[image: usb borescope camera]

Comment: It looks different when it turns versus when it's straight, and you can know the distance from the cable length. 2 foot forward, 90 deg left, 10 forward, 90 right, etc. You could dead recon it.  What is your, better idea?

Comment: @isherwood It won't.  What's your solution though?  I'm curious.